# How To Select Any One Element From a DL List

Tags: jquery, list, codeigniter

I have a DL list with a title in the DT and information in the DD. **I am going to use jquery to select a title from the DT and open the DD when its clicked.** My question is how can I select "just" the DT I click and open that one dd?  Right now when I click on a DT all dd's open and close with the toggle

From the view:

```
foreach($allnews as $row){
echo "<dt class=\"row\">$row->date - $row->subject </dt>";
echo "<dd class=\"show\">$row->news</dd>";
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
   $('.show').hide();
   $('.row').click(function(){
       $('.show').toggle("slow");      
   });   
});
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.row').click(function(ev){
    $(this).next(".show").toggle("slow");      
});
```

[`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`ev.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: or $(this) instead of $(ev.target)

Comment: @RobCowie do you have a good reason to prefer `$(this)` to `$(ev.target)` and it defiantly does not warrent a downvote.

Comment: It works both ways friends, there should be no downvoting here.  Thank you very much to all of you

Comment: @Raynos. Convention primarily; Also, `this` is the element to which the handler is attached. `event.target` is the element that received the click event. It _could_ be a child element. In this example the distinction is probably unimportant but it depends on the content of the `<dt>`.

Comment: Well, your answer has been accepted @Raynos so the OP must think it fits the bill. I'll remove my downvote, though the distinction between `this` and `event.target` should be considered by anyone reading this post. See http://jsfiddle.net/rob_cowie/rS3mj/

Comment: @RobCowie happy times ;). Your right with generic markup `this` is safer. I assumed his markup in `->date` and `->subject` was text not HTML.